# Flex/mxml: newbie layout issue involving TabBar

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

If you run the following mxml code, you'll see there's a gap between the TabBar and the BorderContainer. How to simply remove that gap? I'm having trouble laying it out. Nothing I enter in TabBar (e.g. top="10", or y="10") has any effect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">    

<s:VGroup top="10" bottom="20" left="20" right="20">

    <s:Group width="100%">

        <s:HGroup left="0" top="2">
            <s:Label id="titleTextId" text="My Title" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="18"/>
        </s:HGroup>

        <s:HGroup right="0" verticalAlign="middle">
            <s:Button label="Button1" width="65"/>
            <s:Button label="Button2" width="65" />
        </s:HGroup>

    </s:Group> 

    <s:TabBar id="tabs" dataProvider="{vs}"/>

    <mx:ViewStack id="vs" height="100%" width="100%">

        <s:NavigatorContent label="Tab 1"  width="100%" height="100%">
            <s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="100%" borderWeight="1" borderStyle="solid">
                <s:Label left="3" top="5" text="This is my first tab..."/>
            </s:BorderContainer>
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Tab 2"  width="100%" height="100%">
            <s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="100%" borderWeight="1" borderStyle="solid">
                <s:Label left="3" top="5" text="This is my second tab..."/>
            </s:BorderContainer>
        </s:NavigatorContent>

    </mx:ViewStack>
</s:VGroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the gap attribute, this should do it!

```
<s:VGroup top="10" bottom="20" left="20" right="20" gap="0">
```

Comment: Thanks Nate, perfect! I had no idea there was a non-zero default gap for VGroup.

Comment: Why doesn't `top=` or `y=` work inside TabBar? Is the only way to add vertical space above the TabBar (besides VGroup's gap settings) is by using `<s:Spacer height="10"/>` just above the TabBar?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  The gap that you were seeing was from the layout manager, not the component itself - so you have to get rid of that gap in the layout, not the component.  Make sense?

Comment: Sorry, I started a second question, now that the gap property is set to 0 -- I'm trying to add some vertical space between the label for `My Title` and the `TabBar` component, in a way that won't impact the rest of the layout (as VGroup's gap property does, since it gets added between all components).

Comment: You can go with a spacer element ;)